# write dictionary of lists to a tab delimited file in python, with dictionary key values as columns without Pandas

Tags: python, dictionary

the dictionary I am using is:

```
dict={'item': [1,2,3], 'id':['a','b','c'], 'car':['sedan','truck','moped'], 'color': ['r','b','g'], 'speed': [2,4,10]}
```

I am trying to produce a tab delimited out put as such:

```
item    id
1       a
2       b
3       c
```

The code I have written:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as tab_file:
    dict_writer = DictWriter(tab_file, dict.keys(), delimiter = '\t')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(dict)
```

specifically, I am struggling with writing to the file in a column based manner. Meaning, that the dictionary keys populate as the header, and the dictionary values populate vertically underneath the associated header. Also, I do NOT have the luxury of using Pandas

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Beside the point, but `dict` is a bad name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) a builtin. Use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `dct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work for an ambiguous number of items and subitems in the dict:

```
d = {'item': [1, 2, 3], 'id': [4, 5, 6]}

for i in d:
    print(i + "\t", end="")
    numSubItems = len(d[i])
print()


for level in range(numSubItems):
    for i in d:
        print(str(d[i][level]) + "\t", end="")
    print()
```

EDIT:
To implement this with writing to a text file:

```
d = {'item': [1, 2, 3], 'id': [4, 5, 6], 'test': [6, 7, 8]}


with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in d:
        f.write(i + "\t")
        numSubItems = len(d[i])
    f.write("\n")

    for level in range(numSubItems):
        for i in d:
            f.write(str(d[i][level]) + "\t")
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! @Ruan . However, with this I am still unclear as to how to write to a tab delimited file. Could you please expand on that point?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this using a one-off function and `zip`:

```
d = {
    'item': [1, 2, 3],
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'car': ['sedan', 'truck', 'moped'],
    'color': ['r', 'b', 'g'],
    'speed': [2, 4, 10],
    }

def row_printer(row):
    print(*row, sep='\t')

row_printer(d.keys())  # Print header
for t in zip(*d.values()):  # Print rows
    row_printer(t)
```

To print to a file: `print(..., file='file.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop with a `zip`:

```py
d={'item': [1,2,3], 'id':["a","b","c"]}

print('item\tid')
for num, letter in zip(d['item'], d['id']):
    print('\t'.join(str(num) + letter))

item    id
1       a
2       b
3       c
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to hard code column names you can use this:

```py
d={'item': [1,2,3], 'id':["a","b","c"]}

print('\t'.join(d.keys()))
for num, letter in zip(*d.values()):
    print('\t'.join(str(num) + letter))
```

However the order of the columns is only guaranteed in `python3.7+` if you use a dictionary. If you have a lower `python` version use an `orderedDict` instead, like this:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

d=OrderedDict({'item': [1,2,3], 'id':["a","b","c"]})

print('\t'.join(d.keys()))
for num, letter in zip(*d.values()):
    print('\t'.join(str(num) + letter))
```

Comment: could this be extended with ambiguous key name's? instead of hard coding in the dictionary key name i.e. d['item]? Also, this does not quite achieve my goal of writing to a tabbed file. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, this is still hardcoding in the implication that there are two columns and that they are strings. Additonally, it does not solve my "writing" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *csv.DictWriter* you can also use a module like pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.to_csv(“test.csv”, sep=“\t”, index=False)
```

Probably, you have to install it first by using

```
pip3 install pandas
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @mrzo , you brought up something I should have clarified in my post. I am not able to use pandas. Apologies, this is my first post.